# ext4 cannot delete files after resizing partitions using gparted offline

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

Recently I tried to install a package and got a message saying I didn't have enough space. I guess 25 Gb isn't enough. I downloaded a GParted iso, tossed onto a thumb drive, etc, etc. Everything went great. No issues at all shrinking `/home` and expanding `/`.

Computer runs fine but when I tried to delete a file I got an "Operation not permitted" warning. Can't remove it with `sudo` and password. Can't delete by `chown`ing to root either.

`lsattr` shows `--------------e-------`, but I get the same on files on my second hard drive which wasn't touched during the resizing but is mounted in my home directory. Apparently the ext4 formatted drive is using extents and there is nothing that can change that.

Something is stopping me from deleting files and empty folders from my home partition. Running GParted offline from USB drive is the only thing I have done recently that is not part of my usual usage.

So, what do I do? Reinstall? Reformat as ext4 again or should I use btrfs instead?

Comment: Side note: Gb is not GB, usage of the former is very unusual in the context of filesystems and block devices. Not that it's relevant here, still it looks weird.

Comment: When this happens does `mount` show home's partition as `rw` or `ro`?

Comment: That's a good question, unfortunately I can't answer as running fsck worked immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ext4` filesystem will normally switch to read-only mode if it detects filesystem corruption or I/O errors.

First, make sure you have backups of everything important.

Then, unmount `/home`, run a filesystem check on it, and see what it reports.

Comment: Particularly on SSD, which "gracefully'' fails to read-only when at end of life, if one is in luck (if not, the SSD simply dies).

Comment: Excellent! fsck worked like a charm. This bloody depression I suffer from slows the old noggin down. When I think about it your answer makes perfect sense.